# What is the diffrence between android api 17 and 23?

Tags: android

So, i made a simple game in android studio and everything worked fine on my api 17 device. For some reason it doesn't want to work on my other device with api 23. It instantly stops working. I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with permissions (that was the only thing that i found on google). My app uses only Google game services and sharedprefernces. I'm quiete new so dont hate if the question doesn't makes sense or something.

Comment: If you are crashing, use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 4):

There are many changes. You can check the [version changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels) in the documentation. You should check the log cat for the exact exception if you start to Google for it you will probably find out fast what is going on.